# Is it possible to automatically expand all comments for a Slashdot post?

Tags: slashdot

Occasionally, I'd like to save a Slashdot page to read completely, offline, later.

*Is it possible to expand all comments in one action, instead of manually clicking each one?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the comments, on the bar with the 'Post' and 'Load all comments' buttons there is a slider with two draggable handles:

- The right one sets how many are hidden (score threshold)
- The left one sets how many are full/expanded.

Sliding the left one up to the same position as the right one will make all posts you have set to display, be expanded.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No problem, though I'm not Jacob! :]

Comment: Oops! Mea culpa, J20.